# What are sort or sorts in the context of Maude?

Tags: maude-system

I was reading the manual for the programming language Maude and I found some keyword `sort`. The description of it ([here](http://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/maude2-manual/html/maude-manualch3.html)) is:

- sorts, giving names for the types of data,

does someone know what it means? Is it just defining a type?

Answer (score 1):

`sort` is "a type definition". In Maude, all types are defining an [order-sorted signature](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~fleck/181content/osa1.pdf). However, the `sort` will be empty until you declare its signature by means of `op`.